# Is it possible to disable the focus ring animation in Cocoa for a single app?

Tags: macos, focus

On macOS, you can disable the focus ring animation system-wide with this command:

`defaults write -globalDomain NSUseAnimatedFocusRing -bool NO`

Is there a way to do it in Cocoa for just your own app? I don't want to disable the focus ring altogether. I just want to disable (or modify) the jarring animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just using the `NSUseAnimatedFocusRing` constant in my own app instead of setting it globally.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    // Disable focus ring animation.
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSUseAnimatedFocusRing")

    // etc...
}
```